# is there any way to validate json response in python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to validate a json in python which is a response from a url hitting. How can i validate it in python to make sure that this response is json only or not?

```
def SLRCLDQR011():
try:
    url = 'http://someurl.com/q='
    query = 'running shoes'
    resp = requests.get(url + query)

except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    print 'Domain Name is not reachable'
except:
    print "testcase {0} failed ".format(funcName)
    logfile.write("testcase {0} failed ".format(funcName))
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise
```

Comment: Please don't name your function that. How is anyone supposed to able to tell what that function does in other parts of your code?

Answer (score 3):

Response object have method `json` that will try to parse body of response as a `json`.

```
resp = get("https://httpbin.org/ip")
resp.json()
{'origin': '81.89.63.129'}
```

And for non json responses it'll throw `ValueError`:

```
resp = get("https://httpbin.org/")    
resp.json()
...
...
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

If you want to validate what's in that json use [voluptuous](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous/) or [jsonschema](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema/2.5.1).